# How to get filenames with equal number of elements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, equals

I am querying on a MySQL table. My table consists of two columns:

```
Filename    number of ads
```

How can I query for the files which have equal number of ads?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select * from table where Filename in (
    select Filename from table group by `number_of_ads` having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks @awsumnik. It is too slow . It is been 10 minutes that it is still running although I have limited it to 100 rows only

Comment: check this link if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650039/mysql-select-rows-with-same-values-in-one-column-and-different-in-another